# How to understand the differences of Web Frameworks, Databases, and Libraries?

Tags: database, node.js, angularjs, ember.js, frameworks

**Where I stand:** I am a junior in college. I have a solid background in Java and C++. I've been coding websites in JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and PHP (using MySql databases) since middle school. I have only just uncovered the magical box filled with these mysterious "frameworks."

**My Predicament:** After reading in my spare time wikis, blogs, and StackOverflow questions week after week for the past few months, I feel that I am no closer to understanding the items in this ominous list and how they relate to one another.

1. Yeoman, Grunt, Linemanjs, Bower
2. Nodejs, Go, PHP
3. Mongodb, Couchdb, MySql
4. Angularjs, Ember, Backbone
5. Terms like: boilerplate, scaffolding, frameworks, etc...

**What I am asking:** I understand that explaining any one of the above would be a question too big for a single Stack Overflow question, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I am looking for is a guide that explains in-depth what each of these groups are used for and if/how they can be combined (ex: using Angularjs with Nodejs). I am happy with a link if an article already exists, but I have yet to find an article that covers all of the above.

**El Fin:** I love learning new languages (especially for the web), but right now I feel like I'm blinded, running around in circles like a chicken with its head cut off. A shove in the right direction would be great :)

Comment: The trouble is that the question is WAY too broad.  And there is no correct answer, as anything anyone says will almost certainly be opinion-based.

Comment: I am just at a complete loss. There are soo many great articles that explain the difference between any two of these.. So I'll read an article about Nodejs vs. Angularjs then one about Angularjs vs. Ember then one about Ember vs. Backbone then one on the differences between Backbone and PHP...That's all great individually, but how do they all relate together? I guess I'm looking for the right question as much as right answer.

Comment: Much of what you want comes from the experience of working and using these kinds of tools.  Different problems are best solved with different tools.  Angular vs Ember vs Backbone is a good example - all three are used in major online sites.  The teams picked the tools for different reasons.  You may find some help reading blogs with titles that say "why we picked <a> over <b>" as they'll give insight that you will likely find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this in as an answer to help clarify why this is too broad.

I think that the GREAT BIG point you are missing is that there are specific reasons someone chooses a particular framework or server environment when they start a project.

This is all dependent of a boatload of things that like budget, knowledge, availability, expected scope of the project, etc...  It also may come down to, "I'm starting this new project, what is available in this work environment for me to use?"

Then you don't really get to choose.  You get what you get.

So what's the best package of technologies to use?  That SO depends on what you're doing.

Example:  If you are building a simple site for a local store that just needs a few pages, and you want to keep your costs low.  A simple LAMP solution would work fine.  But if you want to design the next Facebook, even though the core of the system could be build using all LAMP (and it in fact IS), you will need MUCH more powerful servers, and MUCH better and more efficient coding.  Not to mention a boatload of server space for both the site AND the database.

In many cases, when you see people pooling together what might be considered obscure technologies, all they really break down to are collections of libraries. It's like choosing JQuery over some other JS library that essentially does the same thing. One may be better than the other. But you go with what you are comfortable with.

So, when you are asking about how, why, and in which way, do people combine technologies together, there is no way to answer that at all. Other than to say, it's specific to their needs. And that's about it.

Reading articles that compare all these different things together will only give you an idea of what they are capable of, and what their limitations are. In the end, it's always a matter of opinion what is better. Otherwise we would all be coding with the same thing.

For my part, I prefer PHP over ASP. I prefer working straight out of a text editor than using an IDE or any MVC framework. I use jQuery where it's needed, but don't over use it.

But that's just me.

And I'm sure this still didn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! I guess I'm looking for a good way to categorize all this information (I'm not looking for a language that you would recommend). What are the above and how do they relate to eachother? What are MVCs and how do they relate to frameworks? I am just so overwhelmed... Do I just pick any old language/framework and learn it and go from there? How do you begin to understand how all these components work together?

Comment: I can answer part of that.  A "framework" is an entire package from soup to nuts that facilitates all aspects of the project.  Things like .NET fall into that category.  But even .NET uses many different languages.  An MVC is a Model View Controller that is run on TOP of a framework, to automate much of the process of rapid development.  You pretty much only have to work on the "Views" or pages, once the model controllers is built.